# Check wildcard routes in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes

In blade, If we want to check that the current route matches with a route or not, we can simply use:

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'parameter')
{{ 'yes' }}
@else
{{ 'no' }}
@endif
```

But what if we want to match it with a wildcard like:

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'parameter.*')
{{ 'yes' }}
@else
{{ 'no' }}
@endif
```

Is there any solution for that?

I have tried "*" and ":any", but it didn't work.

Note: I want to check route, not URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parth Vora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Laravel's [string helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#strings) function

```
str_is('parameter*', Route::currentRouteName())
```

It'll return true for any string that starts with `parameter`

Comment: Thanks, seems like there is no other way out except string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wanted to toggle an active class based on a URI.

In blade (Laravel 6x), I did:

```
(request()->is('projects/*')) ? 'active' : ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of Blades **Custom If Statements** and write something like this in your `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Blade::if('route', function ($route) {
        return Str::is($route, Route::currentRouteName());
    });
}
```

then you can use it in a blade view like this:

```
<li @route('admin.users*') class="active" @endroute>
    <a href="{{ route('admin.users.index') }}">Users</a>
</li>
```